# Are Differing Store Identifiers Necessary with the Unity IAP Plugin?

Tags: unity, in-app-purchase

I am looking at implementing the new Unity In App Purchasing API for the first time.

Through the [guide](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPDefiningProducts.html) and the [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game-beta), I see that there is the ability to add different store identifiers for product ids that vary across stores... and all the examples reference that way of doing it.

Eg.:

```
public class MyIAPManager {
    public MyIAPManager () {
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        builder.AddProduct("100_gold_coins", ProductType.Consumable, new IDs
        {
            {"100_gold_coins_google", GooglePlay.Name},
            {"100_gold_coins_mac", MacAppStore.Name}
        });
    }
}
```

In my case, my product id's DONT differ, so this seems like unnecessary code bloat to implement it this way... but I don't see any other option?

**EDIT**

Argh, I'm using VS Code on OS X, which is getting better, but still has 
issues, such as having problematic code-completion / API referencing issues, so didn't see the overloaded method option... It's simply enough to do this:

```
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
builder.AddProduct("100_gold_coins", ProductType.Consumable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overloaded method that simply skips the optional Array of IDs if unnecessary... See Edit to OP.

```
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
builder.AddProduct("100_gold_coins", ProductType.Consumable);
```